# Problem initializing UITableViewCell initwithStyle

Tags: iphone, uitableview

cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

---

Still I get the following errors:

/Users/myName/Downloads/myApp/Classes/MyTable.m: In function '-[MyTable tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]':

/Users/myName/Downloads/myApp/Classes/MyTable.m:88: error: 'UITableViewCellStyleValue1' undeclared (first use in this function)

/Users/myName/Downloads/myApp/Classes/MyTable.m:88: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once

/Users/myName/Downloads/myApp/Classes/MyTable.m:88: error: for each function it appears in.)

/Users/myName/Downloads/myApp/Classes/MyTable.m:88: warning: no '-initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:' method found

/Users/myName/Downloads/myApp/Classes/MyTable.m:88: warning: (Messages without a matching method signature

/Users/myName/Downloads/myApp/Classes/MyTable.m:88: warning: will be assumed to return 'id' and accept

/Users/myName/Downloads/myApp/Classes/MyTable.m:88: warning: '...' as arguments.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UITableViewCellStyleValue1 was not defined in SDKs prior to 3.0.  Check the SDK you are using.